# genymotion fails on running with "Fatal IO error: client killed" error

Tags: ubuntu, genymotion

I installed genymotion on Ubuntu 14.04 and when I start it I see in console:

```
eizotov@dev-inviuweb-03:~/genymotion$ ./genymotion
Logging activities to file: /home/eizotov/.Genymobile/genymotion.log
eizotov@dev-inviuweb-03:~/genymotion$
```

In the log file I see:

```
Feb 16 15:32:55 [Genymotion] [Warning] ****  STARTING GENYMOTION  ****
Feb 16 15:32:55 [Genymotion] [Warning] Genymotion Version: Genymotion 2.3.1
Feb 16 15:32:55 [Genymotion] [Debug] [LaunchpadApp] Started with ("./genymotion")
Feb 16 15:32:56 [Genymotion] [Debug] [doRequest] Requesting: "https://cloud.genymotion.com/launchpad/last_version/linux/x64/"
Feb 16 15:32:56 [Genymotion] [Debug] Getting currently authenticated user from  local cache
Feb 16 15:32:59 [Genymotion] [Debug] [HttpRequest::exec] Request timeout (code: 0 ) : "/launchpad/last_version/linux/x64/"
Feb 16 15:32:59 [Genymotion] [Error] Network error while retrieving JSON content:  0
Feb 16 15:32:59 [Genymotion] [Error] [getGenymotionLastVersion] Bad request: "/launchpad/last_version/linux/x64/"
Feb 16 15:32:59 [Genymotion] [Error] Unable to get last Genymotion version number from server:  0
Feb 16 15:33:01 [Genymotion] [Debug] [doRequest] done
Feb 16 15:33:01 [Genymotion] [Debug] Loading "vboxmanage" plugin
Feb 16 15:33:01 [Genymotion] [Debug] Plugin "vboxmanage" loaded
Feb 16 15:33:01 [Genymotion] [Debug] Chipset: "AuthenticAMD"
Feb 16 15:33:01 [Genymotion] [Debug] CPUID 0x80000001 (AMD): ECX= "65"
Feb 16 15:33:01 [Genymotion] [Debug] [VBoxManageCore] Path: "VBoxManage"
Feb 16 15:33:01 [Genymotion] [Debug] VBoxManage ("list", "hostinfo") returns 0
Feb 16 15:33:01 [Genymotion] [Debug] [System properties] Online physical CPU number: 2
Feb 16 15:33:01 [Genymotion] [Debug] [System properties] Online virtual CPU number: 2
Feb 16 15:33:01 [Genymotion] [Debug] [System properties] Max CPU number: 4
Feb 16 15:33:01 [Genymotion] [Debug] [System properties] Max memory size: 2001
Feb 16 15:33:02 [Genymotion] [Debug] VBoxManage ("list", "hostonlyifs") returns 0
Feb 16 15:33:02 [Genymotion] [Debug] VBoxManage ("--version") returns 0
Feb 16 15:33:02 [Genymotion] [Debug] VM engine version: "4.3.20r96996"
Feb 16 15:33:02 [Genymotion] [Debug] VMX/SVM CPU availability: true
Feb 16 15:33:02 [Genymotion] [Debug] VBoxManage ("--version") returns 0
Feb 16 15:33:02 [Genymotion] [Debug] VM engine version: "4.3.20r96996"
Feb 16 15:33:02 [Genymotion] [Debug] VBoxManage ("list", "vms") returns 0
Feb 16 15:33:06 [Genymotion] [Warning] genymotion: Fatal IO error: client killed
```

Firsts I thought that the reason is in connection to "https://cloud.genymotion.com/launchpad/last_version/linux/x64/". But plugins start to load, so I think that it's another reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems it doesn't work via ssh and require launch it directly from machine where Geymotion installed.

you can see this link [reference](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/genymotion-users/6_NxVszDTDk)